# What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?

Tags: xml, xsd

What's the difference between `xsd:include` and `xsd:import`?  When would you use one instead of the other, and when might it not matter?

Comment: See also answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998063/one-xml-namespace-equals-one-and-only-one-schema-file/4998182#4998182

Answer (score 230, accepted):

The fundamental difference between `include` and `import` is that you must use `import` to refer to declarations or definitions that are in a *different* target namespace and you must use `include` to refer to declarations or definitions that are (or will be) in the *same* target namespace.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20070804031046/http://xsd.stylusstudio.com/2002Jun/post08016.htm

Comment: The stylusstudio post that @Pops refers to is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140831005739/http://xsd.stylusstudio.com/2005Mar/post05007.htm

Answer (score 62):

Use **[xsd:include](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#compound-schema)** to bring in an XSD from the ***same*** or no namespace.

Use **[xsd:import](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#composition-schemaImport)** to bring in an XSD from a ***different*** namespace.

Answer (score 23):

Another difference is that [`<import>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1#composition-schemaImport) allows importing by referring to another namespace with the `@namespace` attribute, and/or the schemaLocation with the `@schemaLocation` attribute.

However, [`<include>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1#compound-schema) only allows importing by referring to a URI of intended include schema with the `@schemaLocation` attribute, **`<include>` does not allow the `@namespace` attribute**.

The ability to use the `@namespace` attribute is definitely another difference than inter-intra namespace importing.

For example, the xml schema validator may already know the locations of all schemas *by namespace*. Especially considering that referring to XML namespaces by their schema URL location may be problematic on different systems (i.e. `classpath://` means nothing, or where `http://` isn't allowed, or where the URL doesn't point to the same thing as it does on another system.)

Code sample of valid and invalid imports and includes:

**Valid:**

```
<xsd:import namespace="some/name/space"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="classpath://mine.xsd"/>

<xsd:include schemaLocation="classpath://mine.xsd"/>
```

**Invalid:**

```
<xsd:include namespace="some/name/space"/>
```

Comment: I think you mean _referring to XML namespaces by location URLs_ rather than _by URI_. Namespace URIs (i.e. the `namespace` attribute of `<xs:import>`) are always OK, and considered as an **identifier** (just text, not interpreted), while the `schemaLocation` (a URL not a URI) must typically be processed, to be resolved. And there indeed, the Java-specific `classpath:` URL _scheme_ may mean nothing. But beside this neat-pick, this is a valuable comment, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'm interested in this as well.  The only explanation I've found is that `xsd:include` is used for intra-namespace inclusions, while `xsd:import` is for inter-namespace inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Direct quote from [MSDN: <xsd:import> Element, Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256480(v=vs.110).aspx#sectionSection3)

> The difference between the **include** element and the **import** element is that **import** element allows references to schema components from schema documents with different target namespaces and the **include** element adds the schema components from other schema documents that have the same target namespace (or no specified target namespace) to the containing schema. In short, the **import** element allows you to use schema components from any schema; the **include** element allows you to add all the components of an included schema to the containing schema.

Comment: So, what I get from that description is that import will bring in stuff you refer to only, whereas include means those who refer your XSD will be implicitly getting all the stuff from the XSD you imported

Answer (score -2):

Use xsd:include brings all declarations and definitions of an external schema document into the current schema.

Use xsd:import to bring in an XSD from a different namespace and used to build a new schema by extending existing schema documents..