# XSD with elements from other namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have two XSDs that are definining different documents. Say `A.xsd` defines an element `ElementA` as the root, with some complex rules. Now `B.xsd` defines an element `ElementB` that is supposed to use `ElementA` somewhere in between.

For example I want the XML file for `ElementB` look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ElementB xmlns="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementB">
  <foo>Bla</foo>
  <bar>Blub</bar>
  <ElementA xmlns="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementA">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ElementA>
</ElementB>
```

Then `B.xsd` could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementB" targetNamespace="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementB" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="ElementB">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" />

        <!-- And now I want to include ElementA somehow -->
        <xs:element name="ElementA" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The thing is that I don‘t really want to clone the specification of `ElementA` into `B.xsd`, as there are also documents, that just have `ElementA` as the root (i.e. `ElementB` is some kind of container document).

So, how can I allow `ElementA` within `ElementB` while completely building on top of the already existent XSD?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are actually two different ways to compose XML Schema documents: `<xs:import>` and `<xs:include>`. xs:include is intended to be used when the namespace of the containing document is the same as the one being referenced, so it's not quite what you're looking for. xs:import is better for your situation when you need to reference all (or a subset) of elements in the referenced schema and they're in a different target namespace. There's a question here on the differences: [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357943/whats-the-difference-between-xsdinclude-and-xsdimport).

Anyway, back to this specific question. What you probably want is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementB"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementB"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:ea="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementA">
 <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementA" schemaLocation="A.xsd" /> 
 <xs:element name="ElementB">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" />
    <!-- This introduces a element named ElementA that uses the ComplexType ea:ElementA defined in A.xsd -->
    <xs:element name="ElementA" type="ea:ElementA" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Though you'll need A.xsd to create a complex type for ElementA that you can use in B.xsd as shown.

This arcticle has some good information/examples and includes a discussion of some of the different composability strategies: http://www.xfront.com/ZeroOneOrManyNamespaces.html

Comment: Thank you, that looks quite good, I’ll try that. One question though, where does the `ea:` namespace prefix come from? Or is that the `name` the type definition gets in `A.xsd`?

Comment: Just scroll way to right on the code window - it's referenced as the last attribute in the xs:schema element: `xmlns:ea="http://example.com/namespace/for/ElementA"`. You could give it whatever prefix you want, just as you can for the default target namespace (though everyone always chooses `xs` or `xsd` by convention).

Comment: Oh, didn’t bother to scroll that far and missed that, sorry xD Also thanks for your help, I’ll try this as soon as possible and post my results :)

Comment: @somedave : I am also in a similar kind of situation. But my problem is that the elementB has no namespace declaration whereas only the elemenA has a namespace decalaration. So how should I include only that. Moreover there is no xsd for the element A. The only thing that has to be checked is that if the element A contains that namespace declaration.

Comment: If ElementA has a child element say Bazz, then validation library gives an error on that _"Element 'Bazz': This element is not expected"_. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: What should be the location of A.xsd? In my case B.xsd is trying to import A.xsd but it is not able to find the A.XSD..

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<xsd:import>` tag to import a schema with another namespace.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use that with my example above? Your link does not really explain that..