# XSD: Imported elements of a different namespace are taking up the target namespace of the parent when generating POJOs via the Jaxb plugin

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate POJOs via the maven JAXB plugin to parse the XML I have got. I have a root level element in my XML which has a namespace which is different from the other elements inside it. Following is the XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skuFlatFileType xmlns="http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd" xmlns:ns0="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1">
       <FlattenedSKU>
          <ns0:SKU></ns0:SKU>
</FlattenedSKU>
</skuFlatFileType>
```

Since **FlattenedSKU** and **SKU** are in the different namespace. So I declared a separate XSD for all elements under the FlattenedSKU and then imported it inside the parent one. The XSD look like this:

**sku_wrapper.xsd**

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns="http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd"
     targetNamespace="http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1"
        schemaLocation="sku.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="FlattenedSKU">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SKU" type="ns0:SKU"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
       </xs:schema>
```

The child xsd is as follows:

**sku.xsd**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1"
    targetNamespace="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="SKU">
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now the generated java class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FlattenedSKU", namespace = "http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd")
public class FlattenedSKU {

@XmlElement(name = "SKU", namespace = "http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd", required = true)
protected SKU sku;
```

But what I need is as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FlattenedSKU", namespace = "http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd")
public class FlattenedSKU {

@XmlElement(name = "SKU", namespace = "http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1", required = true)
protected SKU sku;
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Isn't that correct generation of jaxb?

Your element SKU is defined in namespace `"http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd` itself. Only it's TYPE is defined in a different namespace as per your schema

Comment: I am not really sure. I followed this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413145/xsd-with-elements-from-other-namespace but it didn't work. Do you have any idea on how to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: Just posted my answer. Please understand the difference between "creating" an element of type vs actually referring to it. When you create an element of a type defined in other schema, this newly created element belongs to the namespace of schema that you are adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition to my comment what you shall do is "ref" to an element in `sku.xsd` and not create an element in `sku_wrapper.xsd`

So following shall work for you:

**sku.xsd**

```
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1"
    targetNamespace="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="SKU">
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
     <xs:element name="SKU" type="SKU"/> 
</xs:schema>
```

Note that change is declaration of element here.

**sku_wrapper.xsd**

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns="http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd"
     targetNamespace="http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1">
   <xs:import namespace="http://ww

w.xyz/schemas/dbm/product/V1"
        schemaLocation="sku.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="FlattenedSKU">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element ref="ns0:SKU"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Notice the reference of element here

Comment: Yes the ref attribute does the job but now namespace does not appear in the child elements of the generated POJO.


@XmlRootElement(name = "FlattenedSKU", namespace = "http://www.abc/schemas/xyz/sdf/Schemas/Schema.xsd")
public class FlattenedSKU {

    @XmlElement(name = "SKU", required = true)
    protected SKU sku;

Comment: @AryanSingh Did you get past this?

Comment: Yup got past the issue. As mentioned in above comment couldn't get the namespace on the child element though.

Comment: Surprising. I can see the namespace for child as well. Otherwise the model generation does not mean correct. Or may be your child class has namespace defined in its @XmlElement tag