# XSD question - Calling an xsd from another xsd

Tags: xsd

I know I have seen this somewhere before, but I cannot find it again.  I need an example of calling an xsd file from within another xsd.  This is quite useful where a number for xml files are being generated, but where there is large common areas between these xml files being validated.  In that scenario, it is useful to have an xsd that validates the parts common to all xml files, then have separate smaller xsd validation files for the parts of the xml that are specific to each xml file.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably call it *referencing* another XSD file (calling implies that the XSD is run or executed in some way, which isn't the case).

In any case you are probably looking for either the [`import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256480.aspx) or the [`include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256198.aspx) elements, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/05/XMLInfoset" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/IPO" />
  <xs:include schemaLocation="example.xsd" />
</xs:schema>
```

[What is the difference between import and include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357943/whats-the-difference-between-xsdinclude-and-xsdimport)  Use import to reference declarations in a **different** namespace and include to reference declarations in the **same** namespace.