# processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any

Tags: xml, xsd

master.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.gworks.cn/waf_profile"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.gworks.cn/waf_profile" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="profile">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="aspect">
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence minOccurs="1" >
                            <any processContents="strict" />
                        </sequence>
                        <attribute name="id" type="string" use="required"></attribute>
                        <attribute name="class" type="string" use="required"></attribute>
                        <attribute name="desc" type="string" use="optional"></attribute>
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Can I write a XML file against this schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile name="开发" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.gworks.cn/waf_profile"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gworks.cn/waf_profile http://www.gworks.cn/waf_profile.xsd">
    <aspect id="security" class="cn.gworks.waf.config.SecurityConfig" desc="安全配置">
        <security xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gworks.cn/config_security http://www.gworks.cn/config_security.xsd">
            <authService impl="com.bgzchina.ccms.security.SSOAuthService" enabled="true">
                <certificate>
                    <field name="Token" isKey="true" />
                </certificate>
            </authService>
            <authService impl="com.bgzchina.ccms.security.NoAuthService" enabled="true">
                <certificate>
                    <field name="username" isKey="true" />
                </certificate>
            </authService>
        </security>
    </aspect>
</profile>
```

where the child element "security" has its own schema defined.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because the XSD specifies

```
<any processContents="strict" />
```

in the content model of `aspect`, your XML is invalid due to `processContents="strict"`, which **requires that the XML processor must be able to obtain the XSD definition** for, in this case, `security` **and must be able to validate it**.

If you change this to

```
<any processContents="lax" />
```

your XML will be valid, and if you come to define `security` in your XSD, the definition will be used during validation.  (If the definition cannot be found, your document will still be considered to be valid.) This **requires that the content be valid only if XML processor can find its definition**.

If you change this to

```
<any processContents="skip" />
```

your XML will be valid and the **XML processor will make no attempt to validate** the children content under `aspect` (other than that requiring it to be *some* single element per the `sequence` constraint).

**Notes:**

- The default value for `processContents` is `strict`.
- See section [3.10.2 XML Representation of Wildcard Schema
  Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-openness) in the XSD Recommendation for more information.
- If you're wondering about how to bring another XSD into your master
  XSD, see [xsd:import vs xsd:include](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116023/290085).

Comment: Is that valid to specify a xsi:schemaLocation attribute on my "security" element ?

Comment: No, you would bring the XSD containing the declaration of `security` into your master XSD via `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute on `xsd:import` or `xsd:include` as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: But I want to let user to specify the schema for the arbitrary element.

Comment: A type can be specified for an element in an XML document via `xsi:type`, but the type must defined in the XSDs.  XSDs are composed using `xsd:import` and `xsd:include`.  You can use `xsi:schemaLocation` with those.  You can also use `xsi:schemaLocation` on the root element of an XML document instance.