# Why isn't xsd:any validation working as I expect?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to validate the following XML through schema where it should not be validated if there is no text inside the `l10n` element. Also the content element is mandatory for the XML. Please someone suggest me the relevant answer.

The XML to validate would be:

```
<body xmlns="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test">
   <content>
      <l10n xml:lang="en"></l10n>
   </content>
</body>
```

The schema I am currently using is as follows but it is still allowing the above XML to be validated.

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:conf="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/config" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd">
</xs:import>
<xs:simpleType name="nameType">  
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">  
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>   
    </xs:restriction>  
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="content">
      <xs:complexType mixed="true">
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" processContents="skip"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="i18n-value">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="l10n" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="nameType">
                     <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required"/>
                  </xs:extension>
               </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="body">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence><xs:element ref="content"></xs:element></xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous problems here at multiple levels.  Let's tackle them collectively in two phases:  First, we'll repair the XSD problems that are preventing any sort of validation from taking place.

### Repairing initial XSD problems

**This XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<body xmlns="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test try.xsd">
  <content>
    <l10n xml:lang="en"></l10n>
  </content>
</body>
```

**is valid against this XSD:**

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test"
           xmlns:tst="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
             schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="nameType">  
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">  
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>  
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="content">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" processContents="skip"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="i18n-value">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="l10n" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="tst:nameType">
              <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="body">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="tst:content"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Now, your constraint that `l10n` not be empty still remains to be addressed.  Here's how to do this:

- Change `xsd:any/@processContents` from `skip` to `lax` so that you
  can affect validation beneath `xsd:any` via element declarations.  Read more about the differences here: [processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420156/processcontents-strict-vs-lax-vs-skip-for-xsdany):
- Actually define an `xs:element` for `i18n-value`; having a type
  definition alone isn't sufficient.
- Add `i18n-value` to your XML.

Altogether...

### Final XSD and XML

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<body xmlns="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test try.xsd">
  <content>
    <i18n-value>
      <l10n xml:lang="en"></l10n>
    </i18n-value>
  </content>
</body>
```

**XSD**

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test"
           xmlns:tst="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/test">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
             schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="nameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">  
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>  
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="content">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" processContents="lax"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="i18n-value">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="l10n" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="tst:nameType">
                <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="body">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="tst:content"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Kenneth. In my case, body element should be of type i18n-value. Sorry, I missed it in initial question.

    <xs:element name="body" type="i18n-value">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="tst:content"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

Comment: Given that the answer I provided fixed numerous mistakes in your original XSD and worked perfectly for your original XML, I ask that you upvote and/or [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer and ask a new one if you need further help.   Your changed XML really constitutes a completely new question.   Thanks.

Comment: Can you please suggest me Kenneth the answer for the question I just out up in my previous comment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be happy to look at a new question posted as a new question, not in a comment.  As long as you tag it with [xsd] and/or related tags, I'll see it.  Thanks.