# XML inside an string element vs independent elements

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, design-by-contract, contract

What are the conceptual and technical disadvantages of this request/response structure:

**A)**

```
<xs:element name="OrderRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="OrderID" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="OrderType" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name='OrderAttributes' type='xsd:string'/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

where `OrderAttributes` element will contain string in the following XML structure:

```
<OrderName> xy </OrderName>
<OrderDate> xy </OrderDate>
<OrderDetails> xy </OrderDetails>
....lots of other attributes
```

compared to this request/response structure

**B)**

```
<xs:element name="OrderRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="OrderID" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="OrderType" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="OrderAttributes">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="OrderName" type="xs:string"/>
                      <xs:element name="OrderDate" type="xs:date"/>
                      <xs:element name="OrderDetails" type="xs:string"/>
                       ....lots of other attributes
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I need to design web service interface for orders processing, and I am thinking about the  two alternatives mentioned above.

Version A, is more generic, so interface doesn't need to change, when `OrderAttributes` structure changes in any way.

But schema validation is not possible.

And my question is, what are other disadvantages compared to version B. I am analyst, not programmer, so I cannot say, if there is some impact on parsing requests, generating code from contract etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that your generic use of the word ***attribute*** to refer to a property can be confusing in XML, where ***attribute*** refers to a specific construct that stands apart from ***element***:

```
<element attribute="attribute value">
    <childElement>child element value</childElement>
</element>
```

Then, while doing design, you might consider which properties you wish to represent as XML attribute and which you wish to represent as XML elements.  See **[XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element)** for help deciding.

Regarding your **A** vs **B** proposed designs, note that **A** simply is not viable -- you cannot have unescaped markup within an element declared to have `xs:string` content as you've shown.  Furthermore, **A** would then require further parsing of the `OrderAttributes` contents anyway whereas **B** would leverage the XML parser to process `OrderAttributes` contents.  (And, like you said, **B** would not leverage XSD validation either.)

For future expansion, consider instead the use of **[`xs:any`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-any)**, which supports various interpretations of wildcard contents via its `processContents` attribute values of **[strict, lax, or skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420156/processcontents-strict-vs-lax-vs-skip-for-xsdany)**.