# Validate tag inside unknown/ignored tag or under multiple hierarchies?

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces, xsd-1.1, xsd-1.0

I have an XML file with multiple unknown tags that contains known tags to which validation should be added.

```
<root>
  <child>
    <template id="abc"/>
  </child>
  <child>
    <random>
      <template id="abc"/>
    </random>
  </child>
</root>
```

The random tag represents an unknown random tags represented by `xs:any`, I moved to XSD 1.1 to allow having:

```
<xs:choice>
   <xs:element name="child" type="xs:string">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="template" type="xs:string">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="id" use="optional">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern value="[a-z]"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:any/>
           </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>    
   </xs:element>
  <xs:any/>
</xs:choice>
```

My problem is that known tags such as template and child occur inside unknown tags, and under unknown hierarchy of known and unknown tags.

Is there a way `xs:any` can contain known tags or to add validation for known tags and ignore hierarchy, so errors inside known tags would be checked under any hierarchy ?

Any solution in XSD 1.1 or XSD 1.0 is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can anticipate the set of allowed elements, `xs:any/@processContents="lax"` will allow you to constrain their content models.

Alternatively, you can have `xsd:any` allow unknown tags by specifying `@processContents="skip"`, but once you do that, you lose all ability to specify further constraints on those elements, *except via `xs:assert`.*

If you can craft your constraints in terms of `xs:assert` XPaths, you'll be fine.  However, you cannot, as it sounds like you're hoping to be able to do, have a hybrid of `xs:any/@processContents="skip"` followed by `xs:any/@processContents="lax"` or `xs:any/@processContents="strict"` for descendents of the skipped element.   (If you start with `@processContents="lax"`, you can always use `xs:any/@processContents="skip"` deeper in the hierarchy, of course, but not the other way around.)

**See also:** [**processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420156/290085).

Comment: How can I craft the contraints in terms of  `xs:assert` Xpaths If the Xpath is unknown, the Xpath is a mix of known and unknown tags.

Comment: It depends on what constraints you wish to express.  You don't necessarily need to know elements names to write constraints; `*` can match any child element: `every..satisfies` can make statements about sets of unnamed elements; etc.  You won't be able to leverage the intrinsic content modeling constructs of XSD, but you can cover a lot of ground with `xs:assert`.  Really, though, other than spot-check type assertions, stick with `lax` for as far as you can use it.

Comment: in case I have something like that : `<root>
  <child>
    <template/>
  </child>
  <child>
    <random><template/></random>
  </child>
</root> `,  How can apply a regex restriction to an attribute of the template tag ?

Comment: It may be better at this point to ask a new question.  If you do, be sure to specify the conditions under which `template` should have an attribute matching the regex.  For example, all `templates`?  All `templates` that are descendents of `child`?  Only `templates` that are a grandchild of `child`?  Etc.

Comment: I've added a new Question as suggested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340411/xsd-how-apply-regex-to-child-and-grand-grandchild-of-a-known-tag-that-might-oc

Answer (score 1):

Your "unknown tag" is presumably permitted because its parent element allows arbitrary content by virtue of a wildcard (xs:any).

When you specify `<xs:any processContents="lax"/>`, any children of the unknown element whose name corresponds to the name of a global element declaration in the schema will be validated; the effect is that known elements are validated and unknown elements aren't.