# XML schema to allow any combination of nested tags but no mixed tags + [non-tagged]text?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a simple XML schema (XSD) to allow any combination of nested tags (i.e literally any element names) but no mixed tags + [non-tagged]text?

So this would be invalid:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>Some text <tag1>Other text</tag1></root>`

But this would be fine:

`<root><tag2>Some text</tag2> <tag1>Other text</tag1> <tag1>Third text<tag2>Last text</tag2></tag1></root>`

Restated: All content must be between a matched tag pair.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `xs:any` will allow any elements beneath `root` and will not allow mixed content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you also wanted to allow mixed content, you would add `mixed="true"` to `xs:complexType`.

See also [processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420156/processcontents-strict-vs-lax-vs-skip-for-xsdany).

---

**Update to address comment:**

> How about the child nodes of those directly under the ? And all
>   further children down the tree? The default mixed="false" would apply
>   to those too?

No, the above XSD wouldn't prevent mixed content in children of `root`.

To prevent mixed content deeper in the tree, you could use `processContents="strict" and preclude mixed content in the allowed elements.  If this is too restrictive, in XSD 1.1 you could use an assertion:

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="every $e in .//* 
                       satisfies not($e/* and $e/text()[normalize-space()])"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: How about the child nodes of those directly under the `<root>`? And all further children down the tree? The default `mixed="false"` would apply to those too?