# XSD validation says my <any> is not defined

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to build a schema using an `<xs:any />` node. When I validate it says the inserted child nodes aren't defined. I thought `any` allowed me to have undefined child nodes.

My schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="Policy" targetNamespace="Policy" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Request">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="Routing" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My XML:

```
<gp:Request Routing="foo" xmlns:gp="Policy">
  <bar/>
</gp:Request>
```

It flags the `bar` node. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're witnessing the expected behavior for `xs:any/@processContents="strict"`, which is the default value.  When `@processContents` is set to `strict`, the **element definition must exist, and the element in the XML must be valid against that declaration**.

Change to

```
<xs:any processContents="lax" />
```

if you want validation to occur **only if the element definition exists**, or

```
<xs:any processContents="skip" />
```

if you want **no validation to take place** regardless of whether the element is defined in the XSD.

### See also

- [processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420156/290085)