# Why is XSD anyAttribute not working properly?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm developing an XSD file to validate my XMLs and the `anyAttribute` specification doesn't work as expected, at least as how the documentation reports.

I've looked for similar questions or issues on the forum but I found no duplicate.

I want to extend the specified attributes for the `menu` element with the `xs:anyAttribute` but in the validation phase, any other nonspecified attributes return an exception.

This is my schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://www.github.com/overit-official/schemas" targetNamespace="https://www.github.com/overit-official/schemas">

  <xs:element name="menu">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs = 'unbounded'></xs:any>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="layer" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="priority" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:anyAttribute/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element> 

</xs:schema>
```

Here a snippet of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns="https://www.github.com/overit-official/schemas" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.github.com/overit-official/schemas https://www.github.com/overit-official/schemas/geocall-menu.xsd"
      layer="" 
      label="Main menu" 
      icon="../r/std/icons/cartelle64.png" 
      mycustom="foo" 
      priority="3">
...
</menu>
```

When I validate the XML I get this error:

> cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'mycustom' is not allowed to appear
> in element 'menu'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for the `processContents` attribute of `xs:anyAttribute` is `strict`, which requires that the attribute be defined in the XSD in order for validation to pass.

Add `processContents="skip"` to allow even undefined attributes.

### See also

- [processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420156/290085)

Comment: thanks! Solves perfectly my issue!