# XSD for mandatory elements followed by any additional optional elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I need to validate XML. XML should contain the following tags - `country`, `population`, `area`, `capital`. Any additional tag (ex: `citycode`) should be okay even if it's not part of the XSD. My requirement is, I need to accept XML requests coming only from  valid source. Hence I need to check if the request I receive is the one I am expecting since it contains few fields at least which is included in XSD.

I created the below XSD, but I am getting an error:

> Error: Element `'citycode'`: No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<country>
  <population>32225560</population>
  <area>652000</area>
  <capital>Kabul</capital>
  <citycode>123</citycode>
</country>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="country">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="population" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="area" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
```

to

```
<xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
```

or

```
<xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The default value of `processContents` is `strict`, which means it's a validation violation if the XSD processor is unable to obtain the XSD definition for, in this case, `citycode`, and use it to successfully validate the element(s) at the position of the `xsd:any`.  The other `processContents` options allow for the element(s) to be undefined: `lax` won't require definitions but will check the element(s) against any found definitions; `skip` will allow the element(s) without validating them even if definitions are found.

Note that if you wish to allow more than one optional element, add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to `xs:any` because the default allows only up to `1` element.

### See also

- [processContents strict vs lax vs skip for xsd:any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420156/290085)
- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)