# How to validate XML against XSD which import another XSD

Tags: xml, groovy, xsd, xsd-validation

I have 2 XSD files. `DCL.xsd` imports `common.xsd`. 
I have `DCL.xml`. Now, I want to validate `DCL.xml` with `DCL.xsd`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `common.xsd` is properly incorporated into `DCL.xsd` using [**`xsd:include` or `xsd:import`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116023/290085), there is nothing extraordinary you have to do to validate `DCL.xml` against `DCL.xsd`.  Simply associate `DCL.xml` with `DCL.xsd` using the usual methods such as [`schemaLocation` or `nonamespaceSchemaLocation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_schemaLocation).