# Complex XSDs comparison

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, marklogic, xsd-validation

I am currently handling complex XSDs i.e. XSDs which have several imports of other XSDs. I want to compare the changes in the new XSD with the previous XSD, but unable to do it as it is in text format.
A fully generated XSD file would also solve much problem. Any suggestions to compare two versions of complex XSD are welcome.Also wanted to know how to generate the complete XSD if it has several imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to compare the changes in the new XSD with the previous XSD,
>   but unable to do it as it is in text format. A fully generated XSD
>   file would also solve such problem.

By *fully generated XSD*, you probably meant a **flattened XSD**.

Many tools have the ability to flatten XSDs by bringing in `xsd:include`'ed XSDs.  [Search for "flatten XSD"](https://www.google.com/#q=flatten+xsd).  However, be aware that `xsd:import`'ed XSDs cannot simply be brought into an XSD because differing namespaces.

See also [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357943/290085)

Popping up a level, apart from flattening XSDs, there are tools that provide direct XML and/or XSD comparison facilities:

- [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xml_diff_and_merge.html)
- [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com/)
- [Altova's DiffDog](http://www.altova.com/diffdog/xml-schema-diff-tool.html)