# How to import XSDs into an XML file?

Tags: xml, xsd

An XSD file imports 3 XSDs as follows:

```
  <xs:import namespace="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwInt" schemaLocation="SwInt.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="urn:swift:snl:ns.Sw" schemaLocation="Sw.xsd"/>     
  <xs:import namespace="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwSec" schemaLocation="SwSec.xsd"/>
```

How do I include these imports in the XML created from this XSD?

Answer (score 0):

XSDs are not imported into XML files.  XSDs are [imported or included](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116023/290085) into other XSD files.

XSDs can be associated with XML files.  The most common mechanism for establishing that association is via hints conveyed through [`schemaLocation` and `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaLocation)

### Example: noNamespaceSchemaLocation

In the following XML file, `purchaseReport` is in no namespace, and the associated XSD can be found at `http://www.example.com/ReportB.xsd`:

```
<purchaseReport
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.example.com/ReportB.xsd">

   <!-- etc. -->

</purchaseReport>
```

Note that `ReportB.xsd` will have no `targetNamespace`.

### Example: schemaLocation

In the following XML file, `purchaseReport` is in the `http://www.example.com/Report` namespace, and the associated XSD can be found at `http://www.example.com/Report.xsd`:

```
<purchaseReport
   xmlns="http://www.example.com/Report"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/ReportA
                       http://www.example.com/ReportA.xsd">

   <!-- etc. -->

</purchaseReport>
```

Note that `ReportA.xsd` will have a `targetNamespace` equal to the namespace of this XML file (`http://www.example.com/ReportA`).

In your particular case, the master XSD that imports the other XSDs would most likely itself have a namespace, so you would use the `schemaLocation` mechanism in an XML file to hint as to the location of the master XSD that governs the XML file.