# Combining multiple XSDs into a single file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, dataset

I have an XSD file which has 4 `xsd:schema` elements in it, which are related and use each other. I've tried to bind that schema into a dataset with `ReadXmlSchema` method but I've got this error:

> There are multiple root elements

The reason is there are 4 `xsd:schema` in one file. I cannot combine or split them.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Does the provided answer help you understand how to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

> The reason is there are 4 xsd:schema in one file. I can not combine or
>   split them.

You can and you must split them.  An XSD must be a [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) XML document itself, and well-formed XML documents can only have a single root element.

Create a main XSD that uses `xs:include` or  `xs:import` to bring in the other XSDs.   Read more about the differences [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116023/290085).  Examples follow...

### Example using XSD include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="1.xsd"/>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="2.xsd"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</xs:schema>
```

### Example using XSD import

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/main"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/1" schemaLocation="1.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/2" schemaLocation="2.xsd"/>
  <!-- ... -->    
</xs:schema>
```