# Set XML element to no namespace in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate XML according to an XSD. In this XML there are tags with namespaces and without.

```
<my:person xmlns:my="http://my.namespace.com">
  <my:name>John Doe</my:name>
  <my:year>1988</my:year>
  <namespaceLessElement>some value</namespaceLessElement>
</my:person>
```

My XSD looks like this. Validation fails because according to the XSD, `namespaceLessElement` has a namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:myNamespace="http://my.namespace.com"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://my.namespace.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="person" type="myNamespace:person"/>

    <xs:complexType name="person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="year" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="namespaceLessElement" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I can't find any info on how to turn off the namespace for `namespaceLessElement`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the components defined in your XSD are in the namespace defined by its `targetNamespace`.  **Use [xsd:import](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#composition-schemaImport) to bring in an XSD from a namespace different than that namespace:**

### Main XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:myNamespace="http://my.namespace.com"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://my.namespace.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:import schemaLocation="namespaceLessElement.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="person" type="myNamespace:person"/>

  <xs:complexType name="person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="year" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element ref="namespaceLessElement"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

### Imported XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="namespaceLessElement" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:schema>
```

**Then your XML,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my:person xmlns:my="http://my.namespace.com"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://my.namespace.com try.xsd">
  <my:name>John Doe</my:name>
  <my:year>1988</my:year>
  <namespaceLessElement>some value</namespaceLessElement>
</my:person>
```

**will validate as requested.**

### See also

- [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116023/290085)

Comment: How would be the XSD if only the root element has the namespace and not the child elements.

<my:person xmlns:my="http://my.namespace.com">
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <year>1988</year>
</person>

Comment: @BharatDarakh:  Your change of several siblings of `namespaceLessElement` to also be in no namespace would not change the answer's use of `xs:import`; the siblings' definitions would migrate to the imported XSD and be in no namespace as is already shown for `namespaceElement`.

Comment: is this really the only way to remove a namespace from any parameter?

Comment: @ThePrototype This answer is about how to write an XSD that will *validate* XML documents that have some elements in a namespace and other elements in no namespace.  To actively *remove* an XML document's element from a namespace, use a programming language such as XSLT to parse, manipulate, and write out the XML document.