# What scenario was elementFormDefault meant to address, in XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I think I understand the effect that qualified and unqualified have, from answers in [Set XML element to no namespace in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035366/set-xml-element-to-no-namespace-in-xsd)

If I did for some reason want there to be descendent elements in no namespace, I would specify elementDefaultForm="qualified" and use xs:import to import the definitions for those elements, and require XML documents to be explicit about the elements being in no namespace.

But, did someone see a need for locally defined elements to be treated differently with respect to namespaces, than globally defined elements? What was that use case?

Comment: Your question has been flagged as a duplicate based on your headline question. Unfortunately you go on to ask about four supplementary questions, and these have gone unanswered. This illustrates that it's important in SO to ask one question only. I suggest you take one of the supplementary questions, e.g. "why is this document valid" and ask it separately, giving full details of the schema and source document that you are asking about; if you want to ask about the effect of varying the schema or source document, then be very specific about the changes.