# Error on defining complexContent restriction

Tags: xsd, restriction, complextype

I have two schemas.
The first schema defines the type `BasicSequence` (file `Basic.xsd`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://basic-schema.com" 
    targetNamespace="http://basic-schema.com" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:complexType name="BasicSequence">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ElementA" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:any />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="MySequence1">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="BasicSequence">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ElementA" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="ElementB" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>    

</xs:schema>
```

In the second schema I'm trying to define a type based on `BasicSequence`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:basic="http://basic-schema.com" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://basic-schema.com" schemaLocation="Basic.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="MySequence2">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="basic:BasicSequence">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ElementA" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="ElementB" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But during parsing I get the next error:

*Invalid particle derivation by restriction - 'Derived element 'ElementA' is not a valid restriction of base element 'http://basic-schema.com:ElementA' according to Elt:Elt -- NameAndTypeOK.'*

As you can see, `MySequence1` and `MySequence2` have the same structure. But `MySequence1` is successfully parsed and `MySequence2` is not.

Please, help to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange to me that you're trying to use `xs:import` instead of `xs:include`.

See [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357943/whats-the-difference-between-xsdinclude-and-xsdimport) for the detailed information.

Comment: OK, I've replaced `import` by `<xs:include schemaLocation="Basic.xsd"/>`. After that, a schema parser requires `targetNamespace`. I've also added it, and now the schema is valid. But I don't understand, why I need to define `targetNamespace`.